# When do I use `apply` when to use `rollout`?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernete and have a bit confused about `apply` and `rollout` command. If I update the kubernete configuration file, should I use `kubectl apply -f` or `kubectl rollout`?

if I update kubernete configuration and I run `kubectl apply -f`, it will terminate the running pod and create a new one.

but `rollout` also has `restart` command which is used to restart the pod. so when should I use `rollout restart`?

Answer (score 10):

One major difference I can think of is `kubectl apply` can be used for all Kubernetes objects (`Pod`, `Deployment`, `ConfigMaps`, `Secrets`, etc.) where as the `kubectl rollout` applies specifically to objects that deals with some computation like `Deployments`, `Statefulsets`, etc.

Further, `kubectl rollout restart` is useful to restart the pods without requiring any changes in the `spec` fields which is not possible with `kubectl apply`. If we run `kubectl apply` with no changes in the `spec` fields, the pods will not get updated as there is no change to update.

Consider the scenario where some configuration (say, external certificate) is mounted to the pods as `ConfigMap` and any change in the `ConfigMap` do not cause the pods to get updated automatically. `kubectl rollout restart` can be useful in such scenarios to create new pods which can then read updated configurations from the `ConfigMap`.

Also, a important note from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment):

> Note: A Deployment's rollout is triggered if and only if the
> Deployment's Pod template (that is, .spec.template) is changed, for
> example if the labels or container images of the template are updated.
> Other updates, such as scaling the Deployment, do not trigger a
> rollout.

Answer (score 6):

The `kubectl apply -f` used to apply the configuration file kubernetes(where your deploy your desired application).

And `kubectl rollout` is used to check the above deployed application

Example

Suppose your deployment configuration file looks like this and you saved that in nginx.yaml file. Now you want deploy the nginx app from the below yaml file. so you should use `kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml`, and now you want to check if your application deployed successfully or not using `kubectl rollout status nginx`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and if you updated the yaml locally and you want replace that with existing then use `kubectl replace -f nginx.yaml`

Comment: Why? apply -f also works. The question was why use one over other.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Krishna's answer.

Using deployment as an example.

You're using `apply -f <filename>` if you're creating pods for the first time, adding new pods, altering config like replicas or if you have versioned images in the pods and you're bumping up or down the version.

With the last point where you are bumping up or down the version of image (used by the pod), if you were to use the latest and you run `apply -f <filename>` kubernetes is not going to see any change in file. But if you did in fact update the image of the pod and you want to `rollout` the new change, you would have to use `rollout`.

Additionally with `rollout` you can use `revisions` of your rollout (`history`) to go back (`undo`), `pause` deployment and `resume` paused deployments.

For more information on rollout refer to [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)